# How to develop a friends finder for social networking in PHP

Tags: php, social-networking

I want to develop a friends finder that can get the friends list from other mail services like gmail or something. I can use php and mysql. But, I have no ideas to start.
It may be to develop with php?. How can I try? Let me know any ideas.

Comment: Remove 'or something' part from your ideas. Be clear at least for your self about what you want to do. Buy a nice book on PHP/MySQL, start doing something, and when you will have questions, comeback and we will gladly help you.

Comment: Yeah. thank for your advice. I would like to know is that I want to develop friend invitation like from some social network site.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://openinviter.com/

Free, open-source, easy to setup and well-maintained.

Comment: Yeah. I want to do that is like openinviter. But, I don't need a lot of mail services. I want to do my own one and not too much big. Thanks for your link anyway. :)